# Wordpress navbar links using href="#" not working as a dummy link

Tags: wordpress, href, navbar

I am using the free Wordpress theme Expositio (http://expositio.wpshower.com) and when I add a new link to the navbar with href="#", instead of being a dummy link, the system tries to load a new page going nowhere. I did this test with other templates and I did not find this problem. I want to use it in order to create a custom navbar with hidden submenus.

Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like this theme heavily uses AJAX to load further pages, so it likely does not check properly whether a link actually points to a different page or not, and tries to load it as a “new page” in the background any way. Either ask the theme provider about fixing this ... or you will have to dig into the code yourself to try and find out where this behavior is attached to the links, and modify that accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @CBroe I have already contacted them but unfortunately I think they work no longer with this project... Can you orientate me in which type of files should I look for this? The template is pretty simple-coded and it seems not to have so many files...

Comment: Well since this is client-side functionality, I’d start by checking the JavaScript files it comes with.

Comment: There is only one .js file and after debugging the file using some breakpoints, the execution thread does not stop at any of them and the infinite bucle is already running. I suppose that I should look in other files, am I wrong? Any suggestions which keywords can I use to identify the link implementation?

Comment: You could start debugging this from the other end, in your browser - using the developer tools to check what event handlers are getting attached to those links in the first place ... doing this on the example site, it looks like the relevant code starts at line #260 in http://expositio.wpshower.com/wp-content/themes/expositio/js/functions.js?ver=20140321, `$('a').on('click', function(e) {` (Looks like it is not AJAX after all, but they only insert a delay before following the actual link by assigning it to window.location)

Comment: You could either try to modify the selector used there (https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/ might be the easiest approach); or you check what the link points to inside the handler function, and exit the function if it is one of those you don’t want to perform the effect on.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe I finally could make a light change as you suggested and now it is working good! It's the first time I read .js so it is a little hard for me to deal with it.